# Android Global variable source not found

Tags: android

I've declared a global variable class like this:

```
public class globalVar extends Application {
private String globalVar= "";

public String getGlobalVar() {
        return globalVar;
}

public void setGlobalVar(String globalVar) {
        this.globalVar = globalVar;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
        //reinitialize variable
}

}
```

And declared it in my androidmanifest file like this:

```
<application android:name=".globalVar" android:icon="@drawable/icon"   
android:label="@string/app_name">    </application>
```

And tried to set its value in a list under a onclicklistener:

```
((globalVar)getApplication()).setGlobalVar("something");
```

I've got it to work before in another application, but for some reason it's giving me the source not found error...I've been scratching my heads off since this is my only obstacle now, has anyone experience this issue before or has an idea as to why I keep getting the error? Thanks!!

Comment: posting the log would help analyse the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try getApplcationContext() instead of getApplication()

Comment: using getapplicationcontext doesnt work either...I don't understand how it worked before but not anymore in another application...

Comment: Actually I figured it out why it does that. I forgot to declare the globalVar at the application level here: 

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >

So I just changed it to this:

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="globalVar" >

And the source not found error stopped showing up. Thank you guys for all your help regardless!